# Fill DataSet from List of class Items

Tags: c#, dataset

I've searched SO for common questions, but they didn't match my task.
I have a class with many(about 50) `ValueTyped` properties.
And there are needs to fill a `new DataSet` object with class's properties.

For example, if I have this:

```
public partial class MyClass
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    // and other public properties
}
```

I need a two functions to return

1. Filled DataSet with a single row for single MyClass item.
2. Filled DataSet with a multiple rows for multiple MyClass items.

---

```
public partial class MyClass
{
    public DataSet GenerateDataSet(MyClass source);

    public DataSet GenerateDataSet(IEnumerable<MyClass> source);
}
```

I've tried many solutions like below, but it's unable to compile since `DataRow` doesn't have public constructor.

```
var ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(new DataTable("DataTableName"));
var table = ds.Tables[0];
table.Rows.Add(new DataRow(new DataRowBuilder(table, 0)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public partial class MyClass
{
    public DataSet GenerateDataSet(MyClass source)
    {
        return GenerateDataSet(new[] { source });
    }

    public DataSet GenerateDataSet(IEnumerable<MyClass> source)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
        // other columns...
        foreach (MyClass c in source)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.Rows.Add();
            dr.SetField("Name", c.Name);
            dr.SetField("Id", c.Id);
            // other properties
        }
        return ds;
    }
}
```

Comment: `DataRow dr = dt.Rows.Add();` that was that magic code string I was looking last time. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @KamikyIT: you can also use `dt.Rows.Add(c.Name, c.Id, ...)`. But i prefer my approach because then you can specify the columns and their value which is less error-prone.

Comment: I'll mark your answer as correct(SO needs time for this). Again thanks!

Comment: consider "implicit" operator if you want to be super c# fancy : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit